# Is work worship?

Tags: karma, worship

There is a quote "Work is worship"
Working for our goals or just working is it worship to god? 
What does this quote actually mean. Can loving our work lead to god? I really LOVE my work.

Comment: If work is worship, donkey is the best worshiper. Donkey can be called best spiritualist. It's on a light note.:) It depends on the consciousness of the worker.. Activity may be same, it may or may not be worship depending on the consciousness of the worker like what for one is working etc...

Comment: 'work is work' is karma. 'work is worship' is karma yoga.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone born in this world has to work else if he/she ain't working then what exactly will they be doing? But then when we work we need to understand what exactly are we working for? Are we working to fulfill our own desires or is there something else that we are seeking?

As stated in [Bg. 4.18](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/18/)

> कर्मण्यकर्म यः पश्येदकर्मणि च कर्म यः । स बुद्धिमान्मनुष्येषु स युक्तः
>   कृत्स्नकर्मकृत् ॥ ४.१८ ॥

meaning:

> One who sees inaction in action and action in inaction is intelligent
>   among men, and he is in the transcendental position, although engaged
>   in all sorts of activities.

Also, as explained by Sri Prabhupāda [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/transcripts/701225sb-surat/?query=work#bb499493) on what Sri Krishna says in Gita:

> "You simply work for Me." That is life. Is there any counterarguments
>   against this logic? You have to work, but if you work for Kṛṣṇa, then
>   you are saved. If you work for your sense gratification, you'll become
>   entangled—one after another, one after another, one after another.
>   Then you cannot get out of these clutches of repeated birth and death.
>   You have to continue sense gratification—sometimes a man, sometimes a
>   demigod, sometimes an animal, sometimes a tree, sometime an insect,
>   sometime a bird, sometime an aquatic, sometime this planet, sometimes
>   another planet.

When you are working just think that you are serving the Supreme lord, nothing else will matter.

> Caitanya Mahaprabhu clearly says, jīvera svarūpa haya nitya kṛṣṇa dāsa
>   [Cc. Madhya 20.108]. The actual constitutional position of the living
>   entity is that he's eternal servant, eternal servant of God. If he
>   takes that position, then he's safe; otherwise he's not.

So in nutshell if you are working with full devotion and without bothering about the end results, basically you are working for Krishna, which means in a way you are worshiping him.

Comment: Please use transliteration as well